# googlemock how to use mocking in test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm a beginner with google mock and I'm not sure how to use it and the concept.

If I'm trying to Test a method from a class that is calling some other methods from different classes.
Do I need to mock all these methods from this different classes that my Test method is calling.
Here is a example:

```
class A {
public:
    A () {}
    int setnum(int num) {//do some stuff return 1 or 0//
    }


private:
    int _num;          
};


class B {

  public:
    B (){}
    int init(A *a, int number){ 
     if(a->setnum(number))
        return 1;
     return 0;
     }
    void setNum(int num){_num=num;}

  private:
    A *_a;
    int _num;            
};



class C {
  public:
    int doSoemthing(A *a, int number){ 

    if (domore(a,number))
         return 1;
    return 0;
    }

    int domore(A *a, int number){
        if(_b.init(a,number))
            return 1;
        return 0;

        ;}

  private: 
    B _b;        
};
```

Do I need to mock all the methods from class A and B that I need to Test my Test method?
Or can I just mock one Class , and test if this class is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to test C class with mocks, you need to introduce an interface for the dependency than is to be used in C class (here, added BIface). Then you need to use dependency injection of BIface to C class (via added ctor). Having that you will be able to test interactions of B and C classes. IMO A class doesn't need to be mocked in CTest (but most probably need to be tested in BTest)

```
class A {
public:
  A() {}                // not needed
  int setnum(int num) { // do some stuff return 1 or 0//
  }

private:
  int _num;
};

class BIface {
public:
  virtual ~BIface() = default;

  virtual int init(A *a, int number) = 0;

  virtual void setNum(int num) = 0;
};

class B : public BIface {

public:
  B() {} // not needed
  int init(A *a, int number) override {
    if (a->setnum(number))
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }
  void setNum(int num) override {
    _num = num;
  }

private:
  A *_a;
  int _num;
};

class C {
public:
  C(BIface &b) : _b{b} {}
  int doSoemthing(A *a, int number) {

    if (domore(a, number))
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }

  int domore(A *a, int number) {
    if (_b.init(a, number))
      return 1;
    return 0;

    ;
  }

private:
  BIface &_b;
};

class BIfaceMock : public BIface {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD2(init, int(A *, int));
  MOCK_METHOD1(setNum, void(int));
};

TEST(CTest, givenDoingMoreWhenInitOfBReturnOneThenReturnOne) {
  // can be done in CTest ctor if more tests are needed to avoid code duplciation
  BIfaceMock bMock{};
  A a{};                 // `a` doesn't need to be mocked in CTest. It shall be mocked in BTest as it is dependency of B class, not C class
  C testedObject{bMock}; // dependency injection of BFace to C

  const auto SOME_INT_PARAM = 42;

  // Eq mather is used to match both &a and SOME_INT_PARAM. This confirms proper parameters were passed to init
  EXPECT_CALL(bMock, init(&a, SOME_INT_PARAM)).WillOnce(Return(1));

  ASSERT_EQ(1, testedObject.domore(&a, SOME_INT_PARAM));
}
```

Comment: yes that is exactly how i started, but I was not sure if I need to mock class A,This is just a part of the code, it is a little bit complex I have singleton classes and I need to refactor the code to be able to test. But that's the answer I was searching for. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but in your example you don't have to use mocks at all. You can create your objects really easy here.

I would use mocks when I would expect that some method will be called and should return specific value - I'm not testing this method but for example if-statment:

```
 A a;
 if(a.method())
 { 
      // some logic 
 }
```

- To manipulate what if will get I would use mocks like this: `EXPECT_CALL(aMock.method()).WillOnce(Return(true));`
  But you can use it in many more situations (e.g: you can avoid creating really big class and replace it with mock object).

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I edit the code. This is just a simple example I have a much complicated code. So my question is do I need to mock A and B in this example

Comment: Even after code change you don't have to use mocks here. I see one situation if: ```int doMore(){ D d; if(d.isValid()){return 1;} return 0; }``` looks something like this (isValud() - return some value) -> if you want to in easy way control test-flow you can use mocks to accomplish it. Using mocks you can have two simple tests and test if your method return 1 and 0 with proper condition.

Comment: But what if doMore() depends from a method in class A

Comment: You can do it on this case but IMO with this kind od trivial classes you can create real objects(instead od nocka) in test case